# Smoothing of absolute value and sign functions for numerical integration

Tags: numerical-methods, integration, approximation, derivatives, absolute-value

I'm doing Numerical integration of ODEs. for a special system that has an always positive coordinate `s` and a conjugated momentum `ps`.

At some point the equations become so stiff that `s` becomes negative and if I improve tolerances of the numerical integrator, it crashes. To solve this problem, I'd like to approximate the ODEs with `s_new=abs(s)` and `ps_new=-ps` around the critical region (for example `if(s<1.0e-8)`).
The problem is that these are not smooth. Numerical integrators (I use BDF) break down.

One solution that I came across is to use [`arctan`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Smooth_approximation) for `abs` and [`erf`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) for `sign`.

It was hard for me to find anything in literature on it. If you know of a better approach, please let me know. 
Note, there is conservation of energy, so there exist `f(s,ps)` such that `df/dt=0`

Comment: I know nothing about the problem domain, so I am not sure the following is what you are looking for.

Instead of the $sgn(x)$ function, it is customary to use $\tanh (kx)$ for some large constant $k$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:  $2\Phi(x/\sigma) - 1$   as a good approximation to the signum function, where $\sigma$ is small relative to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the failure of the integrator is due to lack of smoothness? It is quite possible to integrate over non-smooth conditions with standard techniques, depending on the character of the system.

If you say that you have a stiff problem, I would imagine that that would be the cause more than anything. Have you tried using a multi-step method instead of a BDF? An Adams-Moulton implicit linear multistep method might be more suitable, and you might be able to avoid this problem altogether. It would help if you posted your system in detail.